# How to solve for the analytic solution of a recurrence relation in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a recurrence such as following:

```
RSolve[{f[m, n] == f[m, n - 1] + f[m - 1, n], 
        f[0, n] == 1, f[m, 0] == 1}, 
        f[m, n], {n}]
```

I tried to use RSolve, but I got an error:

```
RSolve::deqx: Supplied equations are not difference equations 
              of the given functions.
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't know mathematica, but the last two entries don't look like equations to me...

Comment: @btilly: what did you mean here? I am trying to give boundary conditions for the recurrence relation.

Comment: @btilly the last two entries in the RSolve are the function to solve for and the free variables. As pointed out by @Alexey, the last one should be {m,n}.

Comment: Thanks, Simon.  As I said, I don't know Mathematica.  I was just looking at the error message and looking for something that /might/ fit.

Comment: Perhaps you may take a look at http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/Guess/index.php

Comment: @belisarius: I just came back to this question to suggest some of the packages at [RISC](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/risc/software/) - but you've beaten me to it!

Comment: @Simon Did you see http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1385826/ ?:D

Comment: @belisarius: Saw a review of it... do you think some shadowy conspiracy is trying to get us to link to RISC?

Comment: @Simon Nahhhh ... I just mean I read your mind :)

Answer (score 9):

The difference equation and initial conditions are
[image: difference equation]

Mathematica (7 and 8) does not like solving it... both with and without initial conditions. The RSolve expressions are left unevaluated

```
In[1]:= RSolve[{f[m,n]==f[m,n-1]+f[m-1,n],f[0,n]==f[m,0]==1},f[m,n],{m,n}]
        RSolve[{f[m,n]==f[m,n-1]+f[m-1,n]},f[m,n],{m,n}]
Out[1]= RSolve[{f[m,n]==f[-1+m,n]+f[m,-1+n],f[0,n]==f[m,0]==1},f[m,n],{m,n}]
Out[2]= RSolve[{f[m,n]==f[-1+m,n]+f[m,-1+n]},f[m,n],{m,n}]
```

I [know that Mathematica](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/1425/) uses [generating functional methods](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) (probably among other things) to solve such recurrences, but I don't know why it fails in such a simple case.

So let's do it by hand.

Let g(x,n) be the generating function for f(m,n)
[image]

Now examine the sum of f(m+1,n) x^m
[image]

Now solve the simple algebraic-difference equation:
[image]

Which can also be done with `RSolve`

```
In[3]:= RSolve[g[x,n]-x g[x,n]==g[x,n-1]&&g[x,0]==1/(1-x),g[x,n],n];
        Simplify[%,Element[n,Integers]]
Out[4]= {{g[x,n]->(1-x)^(-1-n)}}
```

Now extract the coefficient of x^m:

```
In[5]:= SeriesCoefficient[(1 - x)^(-1 - n), {x, 0, m}]
Out[5]= Piecewise[{{(-1)^m*Binomial[-1 - n, m], m >= 0}}, 0]
```

The binomial is simplified using

```
In[6]:= FullSimplify[(-1)^m*Binomial[-n - 1, m] == Binomial[m + n, m], Element[{n,m}, Integers]&&m>0&&n>0 ]
Out[6]= True
```

So we finally get
[image: Results!]

This can be checked using symbolic and numeric means

```
In[7]:= ff[m_,n_]:=ff[m,n]=ff[m-1,n]+ff[m,n-1]
        ff[0,_]:=1;ff[_,0]:=1
In[9]:= And@@Flatten[Table[ff[m,n]==Binomial[n+m,m],{n,0,20},{m,0,20}]]
Out[9]= True

In[10]:= {f[m,n]==f[m,n-1]+f[m-1,n],f[0,n]==f[m,0]==1}/.f->(Binomial[#1+#2,#1]&)//FullSimplify
Out[10]= {True,True}
```

Comment: @Qiang Li: I know you probably know how to do it by hand... but I had made such a nice notebook...

Comment: @Simon, I appreciate your effort. But you, instead of mma, did most of the work. :)

Comment: +1, I have to look at generating functions, I've never used them.

Comment: @Qiang Li: I've found that mma is useful for doing a lot of things, and can often lead you in directions you would never have thought of. However, I have found that spending a little extra time examining the problem by hand gives superior results. But, that's true of any programming language.

Comment: @rcollyer: I've never used them enough. The book I linked to, [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) and [Wilf's](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/) other book [A=B](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) (written with others) are definitely worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer but it seems that the right form should be (note `{m, n}` at the end):

```
RSolve[{f[m, n] == f[m, n - 1] + f[m - 1, n], f[0, n] == 1, f[m, 0] == 1}, f[m, n], {m, n}]
```

*Mathematica* leaves this unevaluated. I think it just cannot solve this.

Comment: but this is a very simple function, f[m,n]=Binomial[n+m,m]. Mma cannot solve it?

Comment: I think that most CASs struggle to solve 2-variable recurrence relations... Don't know why though, this one's not that hard.